# Converting Differential Operator to Integral Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

The Green's function of following differential operator

$$(\mathcal{L}y)(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\,\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-\frac{n^2}{x}\,y(x), \:0<x<1$$

with boundary conditions
$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$
 can be the form of 
$$G(x,t)=  \begin{cases} 
     \dfrac{1}{2n} \left(\dfrac{x}{t}\right)^n(1-t^{2n})& x\leq t\\
      \dfrac{1}{2n} \left(\dfrac{t}{x}\right)^{\!n}(1-x^{2n}) &  x>t
   \end{cases}.
$$

Now using this, I would like to convert the following ODE to an integral equation for nonzero number $n$ (which I got stuck in)
$$x^2y''+xy'+(\lambda x^2-n^2)y=0$$
$$y(0)=y(1)=0. $$
We also can write the above equation in $\mathcal{L}y(x)+\lambda xy=0$ relavant to $y(0)=y(1)=0$, so it may be correct to say
$$\int_0^1G(x,s)(\mathcal{L}y(s)+\lambda sy(s))\,ds=0$$

So now it equals $\displaystyle y(x)+\lambda \int_0^xG(x,s)sy\,ds+\lambda \int_x^1G(x,s)sy\,ds=0$.

I'm confused here, since I assumed $\displaystyle y(x)=\int_0^1G(x,s)Ly(s)\,ds $ from this http://www.nada.kth.se/~annak/greens1d_odes.pdf

However from Zeyman, I think we have $\displaystyle Ly(x)=\int_0^1G(x,s)Ly(s)\,ds$, since $G(x,y)$ is a kernel. Anyways, I'm not sure how to solve this question; I appreciate any help.